# Split array into differently N sized chunks

Tags: arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I was wondering if this is possible in VueJS

I have an array of N items, and I want to split it into arrays of different lengths to ultimately output something like this (note the first row has two columns, and the second has 3)

```js
Array = [{"text": "hello"},{"text": "hello1"},{"text": "hello2"},{"text": "hello3"},{"text": "hello4"},{"text": "hello5"},{"text": "hello6"},{"text": "hello7"},{"text": "hello8"}]
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-2">
       hello
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-2">
        hello1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-of-3">
       hello2
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        hello3
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-of-3">
        hello4
    </div>
</div>
```

And repeat

I would think that you need to chunk the array but the examples I've seen assume a fixed N length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to deal with this is to use a computed.

Take the array, and nest as needed (not sure what your rules are for having 2 then 3)

and then use nested loops in the template to show the data

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      split: "2,3",
      items: [{"text": "hello"},{"text": "hello1"},{"text": "hello2"},{"text": "hello3"},{"text": "hello4"},{"text": "hello5"},{"text": "hello6"},{"text": "hello7"},{"text": "hello8"},{"text": "hello9"}]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      const { split, items } = this;
   let ret = [];
      let si = 0;
      let ci = 0;
      let splitArr = split.split(',');
      this.items.forEach(item => {
        if(!ret[si]){ret.push([])}
        ret[si][ci] = item
        ci = (ci + 1)
        if (ci >= splitArr[si % splitArr.length]) {
         ci = 0;
          si++;
        }
        
      })
      return ret
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.row{
  display: block;
}
.col{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
.col-1-of-1{
  width: calc(100% - 4px);
}
.col-1-of-2{
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
.col-1-of-3{
  width: calc(33.3% - 4px);
}
.col-1-of-4{
  width: calc(25% - 4px);
}
.col-1-of-5{
  width: calc(20% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    SPLIT: <input v-model="split">
  </div>
  <div class="row" v-for="row in rows">
    <div :class="`col col-1-of-${row.length}`" v-for="col in row">
      {{col.text}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works okay. Im trying to figure out how to divide up the array in the first place :D

Comment: can you elaborate what the logic is, how is the separation happening?

Comment: updated code to dynamically change based on text input

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items: [{"text": "hello"},{"text": "hello1"},{"text": "hello2"},{"text": "hello3"},{"text": "hello4"},{"text": "hello5"},{"text": "hello6"},{"text": "hello7"},{"text": "hello8"}],
      size: 2
    }
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      let _newContent = [];

      while(this.items.length > 0) {
        _newContent.push(this.items.splice(0, this.size));
      }

      return _newContent;
    }
  },
})
```

Comment: I think you might have missed the fact I want different N sizes, so 2 then 3 then 2 then 3 etc, not just 2,2,2,2,2

Comment: @user5067291, yeah i checked that, but i answered that if he/she want to change dynamically change the formation of chunk size

Comment: @user5067291 i do not provide exact code, i want to just give him a basic concept of chunk any amount of N size array that's it